# Kendo Grid does not show text as I type it into the cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.SettlementMemoViewModel>()
  .Name("SettlementMemodGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
 {
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.TaxYear).Width(50).Title("Tax Year");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.OriginalAssessment).Width(100).Title("ORIG. ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:##########0}");
  //columns.Bound(nr => nr.Reduction).Width(100).Title("REDUCTION");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.Reduction)
          .Width(100)
          .Title("REDUCTION")
          .ClientTemplate("<input class='reduction-input' name='Reduction' onchange='calculateFinalAssessment(this)' />");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.FinalAssessment).Width(100).Title("FINAL ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:###,###,##0}");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.Rate).Width(100).Title("RATE");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.RefundSavings).Width(100).Title("REFUND/SAVINGS");
    columns.Bound(nr => nr.Type).Width(100).Title("TYPE (R S R/S)");
 })
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
 .Pageable()
 .Scrollable()
 .Events(e => e.Edit("OnEditStart"))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
 .Ajax()
 .Batch(true)
 .ServerOperation(false)
 .Model(model =>
 {
      model.Id(n => n.TaxYear);
      model.Field(n => n.OriginalAssessment).Editable(false);
      model.Field(n => n.Reduction).Editable(true);
      model.Field(n => n.FinalAssessment).Editable(false);
      model.Field(n => n.Rate).Editable(true);
      model.Field(n => n.RefundSavings).Editable(true);
      model.Field(n => n.Type).Editable(true);
  })
.PageSize(20)
.Read(read => { read.Action("FetchSettlementMemoGrid", "Forms").Data("BuildObjectGridSettMemo"); })
 )
)
```

When the page is rendered, this is what the grid looks like:

[image]

When I click in the cell to enter a value in the Reduction column, the cell becomes editable and I assume the cursor is in the cell but when I type, I dont see any numbers being entered.  As you can see from this image, I am editing the first row of the grid (it gets highlighted green).

[image]

But when I click in the Reduction column on the second row, the value that I entered in row 1 appears.

[image]

So the value is getting entered, I just can't see it until I mouse over a different row.

And, just so you have it, this is the javascript that runs when the value of the reduction column changes:

```
function calculateFinalAssessment(input) {
    var grid = $("#SettlementMemodGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = $(input).closest("tr");
    var originalAssessment = grid.dataItem(row).OriginalAssessment;

    var reduction = parseFloat(input.value);

    if (isNaN(reduction)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid numeric value for Reduction.");
        return;
    }

    var finalAssessment = originalAssessment - reduction;
    console.log(finalAssessment)

    // Update the data item with the new FinalAssessment value
    grid.dataItem(row).FinalAssessment = finalAssessment;

    // Refresh the row in the grid to reflect the updated FinalAssessment value
    grid.refresh();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: It may be your css rules. If you reselect row 1, does the value disappear again?

Comment: @NigelK - yes. Any time I click in the cell, the value disappears

Comment: You'll need to inspect the element with the browser tools, in its 'invisible' state, and work out what the problem rule is. Turn off each rule until you find the one causing the problem. If the value is actually there you'll be able to see it in the DOM.

Comment: Why won't you use the default behaviour ([here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)) ? You don't need to set the template, kendo creates it for you. If you really need to create an input, you should create it with [edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) and bind the model to it, to make kendo know that input is related to a field.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - I would rather use default behavior but this was the only way I was able to figure out how to get the "Reduction" column to work as an input.  I tried adding style='color:black;' into the <input>  in the client template and now the text in the input box shows as I type the number in but now as soon as I tab off the input, the text disappears.

Comment: Check out [this example](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom).  I did a more simple example reproducing what you want to do [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/iNEDeLIB). Doing this way kendo grid binds its field with the input. But I'm not sure how to do that in asp.net.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - Thanks for the assistance.  I ended up setting up an editor template and removed the client template and that cleaned up everything.